# Do I have to place "RewriteEngine on" every time when I place it in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I've a pretty large htaccess about 400 lines and 30 of theme are filled with "RewriteEngine on" do I really have to place it every time before a script or is one time in the first line of the htaccess enough?

Thanks, Sake

Comment: Just one `RewriteEngine on` at top is good enough..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it's in the same scope as the rest of your rules, you only need it once, and it doesn't even need to be at the very top.

By scoping, I mean:

```
<Files "*.php">
    RewriteEngine On
    (some rules)
</Files>

(some more rules)
```

isn't going to work, because if the request isn't for a PHP file, the `RewriteEngine On` isn't going to get applied, and the "some more rules" part won't do anything.